# Delay canActivate call when page refreshes in order to wait for the data to load

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-ui-router, canactivate

When I reload my page, it always goes to blank page instead of the same page. The reason behind this is canActivate method which is cheking for user's permission gets invoked as soon as user refreshes the page and it is not able to get user data immediately. User data comes after some seconds.
Is there any way to make canActivate method wait till data comses? I have been going through RxJS's page but not understanding how to do it.
Can someone suggest me any ideas?

```
  constructor(private router: Router, private userDataService: UserDataService) {
    userDataService.userData$.subscribe(
      (data: User) => {
        this.userData = userData --> comes after some seconds
      }
    );
  }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):         
     Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree 
  {
    const result = this.getUserData(route);
    if (!result) {
      this.blankPage();
    }
    return result;
  }


public getUserData(): Observable<boolean> {
    if (this.userData) {
        check for permissions...
        return of(true);    
    }
    return of(false);
}
```

userdata.service.ts:

```
  userDataSubscription: Subscription;
  userData: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);
  public userData$: Observable<User> = this.userData.asObservable();
  
  
  private getUserData(): void {
    const userData$ = new Observable(
      subscriber => subscriber.next(new User())
    ).pipe(
      delay(1000),
      mergeMap((model: User) => this.getUserInfo(model)),
      mergeMap((model: User) => this.getUserPermission(model)),
      catchError((err, caught) => {
        console.error('failed')
        return caught;
      })
    );
    this.userContextDataSubscription = userData$.subscribe(
      (data: User) => {
        this.userData,next(model);
      },
      () => console.error('failed')
    );
  }
```

Comment: "The same page" does not exist anymore once you hit a (hard) refresh. From that point on the browser is responsible again and will show a blank page until your application gives it something to display initially. Your best bet seems to be a loading-screen that's showing until the angular app loaded (or a route of any kind).

Comment: @PhilippMeissner Thanks for the reply. I am anyways showing loadinScreen but in route it will be blank after loading is finished . and that's why it is not going back to my old route. it goes to localhost:4200/#/ instead of localhost:4200/#/my-comp

Comment: On a first glance I noticed that you manually subscribe to the observable. No need - Just have your `canActivate` return an observable that resolves to a `boolean`. Something like: https://gist.github.com/PhilippMeissner/ccfc298a6e7c9ab0b22b4a261ed022f3

Comment: @PhilippMeissner. let me try this..

Comment: @PhilippMeissner After refresh, it still goes to localhost:4200/#/

Comment: Then it is a deeper issue with your routing and guards. You may have to further update the question with related code.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner.. i have added a method which I am subscribing

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use an Angular [resolver](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) here instead of a guard. A resolver ensures data is available and loaded before a route loads.

There are lots of useful tutorials, just search for "Angular Resolver".

A resolver returns an Observable. You probably want to use the RxJS filter and take(1) operators. Something like this:

```
resolve(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
  return this.service.getMyData(route.paramMap.get('id')).pipe(
    filter(x => !!x),
    take(1)
  )
}
```

Filter here ensures the data is a truthy value. Then take(1) basically says I got what I need. All the best.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this but unfortunately, I can not use Resolver but I will go through it for my understanding

Answer (score 0):

`canActive` is an asynchronous method it means you can return Observeble or Promise and the route will not be loaded until Observable/Promise gets resolved
here is an example of correct `canActivate` usage:

```
     canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot):         
         Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree 
      {
        return this.userDataService.userData$
          .pipe(take(1))
          .pipe(map(user => {
            let result: boolean
            // check your permissions
            if (!result) {
               this.redirectToBlankPage();
               return false;
             }
             return result;
          }));
      }
```

Comment: you mean I need to remove my subscription from the constructor and put it in canActivate method?

Comment: @Radiant you do not need to subscribe in the constructor and save results to the class field since user data there can be resolved after `canActivate` will be executed, so when `canActivate` is called userData is always empty for you and the blankPage() will be always called (is it your problem if I'm correct)

Comment: Exactly...when I reload the page, userData is always null/undefined/empty and after some seconds, it comes. Meanwhile canActivate already got false as a response and route goes to blank page and url is localhost:4200/#/ instead of  localhost:4200/#/my-comp

Comment: @icekson..acording to your answer, it does not show blank page any more but the page where there is no security guard applied. This could work but is there any way to wait for the userData to come and then load the same page again instead of some other page?